# How to get continuously updating environment variable in batch file

Tags: batch

I would like to access the updated environment variable in 2nd Batch file, which is changing continuously using 1st batch file.

The e.var changing continuously using 1st batch file but I am getting only one value assigned to the E.variable after starting 2nd batch file.

For Example:

#### 1st batch file:

```
:start   
setx ev=%random%
sleep 5s
goto start:
```

#### 2nd batch file:

```
:start    
echo %ev%
sleep 10s  
goto start:
```

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/171588/1030702) answers your stated question. However, I would like to ask you [what you are trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/187228) - your current example seems like a rather hackish attempt to do *something*, and there might be a more elegant way to do this *something* if you tell us what it is.

Answer (score 5):

Probably there is some misunderstanding regarding environment variables. Those are **not** shared  between running processes (think about all the chaos this would lead to), but **every** process runs in it's **own** environment.

Changing environment variable `ev` of process A will have no effect on setting or changing the environment variable `ev` of process B.

The new environment for a starting process is created by **copying** the environment of its "parent" - the process that started it. That's why you still see the value once set to the environment variable `ev` in process A. It got copied to the environment of your new process running your 2nd batch.

While the variable `ev` in A's environment keeps constantly changing the variable`ev` in B's environment will keep constant.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 `.bat` files work fine when run in 2 separate Command Prompt windows

1st.bat:

```
@echo off
:start
setx ev %random%
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
goto start:
```

2nd.bat:

```
@echo off
:start
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Environment" /v ev ^|FIND "ev"') DO set ev=%%B
echo %ev%
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
goto start:
```